# Why Java Step Return hits break point

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I have a simple Java class Fraction with chained constructors

```
public class Fraction {

 private int numerator;
 private int denominator;

 public Fraction(){            // no-arg constructor
 -> setNumerator(0); 
    setDenominator(0);
 }

 public Fraction(Fraction f){  //copy constructor
 -> this(f.getNumerator(), f.getDenominator());
 }

 public Fraction (String sFraction){ // String input constructor
 -> this(sFraction.split("/")[0], sFraction.split("/")[1]);
 }

 public Fraction(String sNum, String sDenom){ // Double string constructor
 -> this(Integer.parseInt(sNum), Integer.parseInt(sDenom));
 }

 public Fraction(int iNum, int iDenom){  // two int constructor
 -> this.setNumerator(iNum);
    this.setDenominator(iDenom);
 }
}
```

And I have breakpoint on first line of each constructors (Marked by ->). Now if I stop at a breakpoint in one of the constructors and hit "Step Return" in Eclipse IDE, the execution stops at next chained constructor breakpoint, instead of returning back from the constructor. I don't understand this behavior. I thought Step Return should complete execution of the method and return. Then why is it hitting the breakpoint in the next chained constructor?

Comment: All active breakpoints still apply. Once the first breakpoint is reached try disabling all breakpoints, then hit step return, then re-enable all breakpoints.

Comment: @AndrewS Thanks. That was the answer I was looking for. I know disabling all the breakpoints after hitting the first one then Step Return would work as expected, but I did not find any official documentation that says all the active breakpoints would be hit before returning. Do you know any official documentation mentioning this.

Comment: No - nothing directly mentioned that I know of.  The [doc](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fdebug%2Fref-executioncontrolcommands.htm&cp=1_4_7_2_0) describes Step Return in isolation, with no mention how it interacts with other execution control commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See explained details about **Step Return** just below.

All active breakpoints will produce a debug cursor stop, no matter if you do `resume`, `step into/over/return`. The cursor will be stopped where you have an active breakpoint and the code will execute. (And from my perspective) I would say thank God it does it. Sometimes you add your breakpoints all over the code as you are not really sure where the smell is/come from ;)

It is more simple to "Skip all breakpoints" when you don't need the stops. There is a [image: Skip all breakpoints] `CTRL+ALT+B` shortcut to toggle this function between skip all breakpoints. Or just disable the points one by one when you don't need them.

[More details can be read here.](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fdebug%2Fref-executioncontrolcommands.htm&cp=1_4_7_2_0)

---

### The differenct debug execution steps are:

[image: Resume] **Resume**

> *Resumes a suspended thread.*
>
> (To resume the execution of the currently suspended debug target.)

[image: Step Into] **Step Into**

> *Steps into the highlighted statement.*
>
> (To step into the next method call at the currently executing line of code.
> To step into a method you must have execution suspended and be stepping through code.)

[image: Step Over] **Step Over**

> *Steps over the highlighted statement. Execution will continue at the next line either in the same method or (if you are at the end of a method) it will continue in the method from which the current method was called. The cursor jumps to the declaration of the method and selects this line.*
>
> (To step over the next method call (without entering it) at the currently executing line of code. Even though the method is never stepped into, the method will be executed normally.
> To step over a method you must have execution suspended and be stepping through code.)

[image: Step Return] **Step Return**

> *Steps out of the current method. This option stops execution after exiting the current method.*
>
> (To return from a method which has been stepped into. Even though we return from the method, the remainder of the code inside the method will be executed normally. To step return from a method you must have execution suspended and be stepping through code.)

[image: Suspend] **Suspend**

> *Suspends the selected thread of a target so that you can browse or modify code, inspect data, step, and so on.*
>
> (To halt the execution of the currently selected thread in a debug target. Once the selected thread is suspended you can then examine its stack frames.)

[image: Terminate] **Terminate**

> *Terminates the selected debug target.*
>
> (To terminate the launch associated with the selected debug target. Once a launch is terminated it can be automatically removed from the Debug View. To change this setting use the Run/Debug -> Launching preference page.)

[image: Terminate & Relaunch] **Terminate & Relaunch**

> *Terminates the selected debug target and relaunches it.*
>
> (To first terminate the selected debug target and secondly, relaunch it. Once a launch is terminated it can be automatically removed from the Debug View. To change this setting use the Run/Debug -> Launching preference page.)

[image: Terminate & Remove] **Terminate & Remove**

> *Terminates the selected debug target and removes it from the view.*
>
> (To terminate the launch associated with the selected debug target and remove it from the Debug View.)

[image: Terminate/Disconnect All] **Terminate/Disconnect All**

> *Terminates all active launches in the view.*
>
> (To terminate all the running debug targets in the Debug and Console View. If the target cannot be terminated, it will be disconnected. Once a launch is terminated it can be automatically removed from the Debug and Console View. To change this setting use the Run/Debug -> Launching preference page.)

Comment: I know what Step Return means. I was not sure why it was hitting other break points when exiting.

Comment: I have updated the answer with updates, and the detailed information link. And all breakpoints you have active will be debug cursor on, no matter if you do step into, over, or return. The cursor will be stopped where you have an active breakpoint and the code is executed. (And from my perspective) I would say thank god it does it. Sometimes you add your breakpoints all over the code and you are not really sure where the smell is. It is more simple to disable and enable when your need tells you ;)

Comment: please add the last part of your comment (that all the active breakpoints will hit) to the answer :)